# How did my job's Smart Card become able to authenticate into my personal Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, authentication, smart-card

**Quick History:** I purchased a 2023 Macbook Pro 16" a few months ago and promptly *followed some guide that enables Smart Card authentication for DOD sites in Firefox.*  I wish I knew all the actions I did, but I think my ADHD got the best of me cuz I don't seem to have documented anything.

**Issue:** When my Smart Card is inserted into my CAC reader, and I use `sudo` or try to unlock the screen, it prompts me for my Smart Card PIN instead of my local account's password or fingerprint.

**Questions:** I think I can fix it via a combination of `sc_auth identities` and `sc_auth unpair -h`*`[hash]`*, but before I do that:

1. Will the commands above affect my ability to authenticate into work-related web sites and VPNs with my Smart Card, or does it strictly only remove authenticating into my laptop with my Smart Card?
2. What could I have done that paired my Smart Card to my local account (so that I can avoid doing this later)?

Comment: You've got a card reader hardware device attached, presumably with controlling software? Any idea what "some guide" might be?

Comment: Correct, I have a USB smart card reader.  I wish I knew which guide/tutorial I used online.  I remember there were a bunch I was using to figure out how to enable Smart Card authentication in Firefox.